# map .vue files in the components folder and export it as a json

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to map all .vue files in the components dir. and create .json file in the root dir. my vue.config.ts file looks like below. but the method I created not running.

```
function createComponentsMapJsonPlugin() {
  return {
    apply: (compiler) => {
      compiler.hooks.done.tapPromise('CreateComponentsMapJsonPlugin', () => {
        const componentsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'src/components')
        const componentsMap = {}

        const files = fs.readdirSync(componentsDir).filter(file => {
          return file.endsWith('.vue') && file !== 'index.vue'
        })

        files.forEach(file => {
          const name = file.replace('.vue', '')
          componentsMap[name] = path.join(componentsDir, file).replace(/\\/g, '/')
        })

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const filePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'componentsMap.json')
          fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(componentsMap), (err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
            } else {
              resolve(true)
            }
          })
        })
      })
    }
  }
}

function configureWebpack(config) {
  const newConfig = { ...config }
  newConfig.plugins.push(createComponentsMapJsonPlugin())
  return newConfig
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  ...
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/")
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        format: 'es'
      }
    }
  },
  configureWebpack,
})
```

the `apply: () =>` isn't calling. is there better way to achieve map the components folder and export it as a .json file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example, it also scan the folder recursively

Be aware of this structure:

```
components
└───user
│   │   Card.vue
└───product
    │   Card.vue
```

If the component from different folder have same name then it will override file and will output something like this:

```json
{ Card: ".../src/components/product/Card.vue"}
```

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

async function getFiles(dir) {
    const dirents = await fs.readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
    const files = await Promise.all(
        dirents.map((dirent) => {
            const res = path.resolve(dir, dirent.name);
            return dirent.isDirectory() ? getFiles(res) : res;
        })
    );
    return files.flat();
}

function createComponentsMapJsonPlugin() {
    return {
        apply: (compiler) => {
            compiler.hooks.done.tapPromise('CreateComponentsMapJsonPlugin', async () => {
                const componentsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'src/components');
                const outputPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'componentsMap.json');

                const filesList = await getFiles(componentsDir);
                const filesMap = filesList.reduce((acc, filePath) => {
                    const formattedPath = filePath.replace(/\\/g, '/');
                    const file = formattedPath.split('/').at(-1);

                    if (file.endsWith('.vue') && file !== 'index.vue') {
                        acc[file.replace('.vue', '')] = formattedPath;
                    }

                    return acc;
                }, {});

                return fs.writeFile(outputPath, JSON.stringify(filesMap));
            });
        }
    };
}

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins.push(createComponentsMapJsonPlugin());
    }
};
```